# React refs not giving the correct output for input field

Tags: reactjs

React ref not giving the correct output. It returns '**refr < input type="text" placeholder="ssssssssss" >​**' instead of ref objects that contain functions like focus etc.

Please check the below code -

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input 
          type="text" 
          ref={(refr) => console.log('refr', refr)} 
          placeholder='ssssssssss'/>
      </div>
    )
}
```

So in the console, it prints log as **'refr < input type=​"text" placeholder=​"ssssssssss" >​'**. Is there any issue with this?

Answer (score 0):

The ref attribute return  a reference to the element or component the ref is on.

try this code :

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input 
          type="text" 
          ref={function(param) {console.log(param)}}
          placeholder='ssssssssss'/>
      </div>
    )
}
```

for more detail read this article https://www.reactenlightenment.com/basic-react-components/6.9.html

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example of using refs for the input element

```
class CustomTextInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.focusTextInput = this.focusTextInput.bind(this);
  }

  focusTextInput() {
    // Explicitly focus the text input using the raw DOM API
    this.textInput.focus();
  }

  render() {
    // Use the `ref` callback to store a reference to the text input DOM
    // element in an instance field (for example, this.textInput).
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }} />
        <input
          type="button"
          value="Focus the text input"
          onClick={this.focusTextInput}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Reference [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)